# focus on page load (works if refreshed)

Tags: javascript

How can I make my page focus automatically on the field

```
        <script>
    function focus(event) {
            document.getElementById('keywords').focus();
    }
</script>


<BODY onload="focus(event)"></body>
```

appears to work but only if i refresh the page is there a way to make it focus automatically on the page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First include jQuery, then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#keywords').focus();
})
```

Comment: this still needs a refresh? i think the page may be caching? might need to force a refresh?

Comment: `code`    <script>
        function focus(event) {
                document.getElementById('keywords').focus();
        }
    </script>

<div id="cms">
<?php echo tep_draw_form('quick_find', tep_mobile_link(FILENAME_ADVANCED_SEARCH_RESULT, '', 'NONSSL', false)) ?>
 <label for="keywords" ><?php echo TEXT_KEYWORDS . ':'; ?></label>

 
  <?php echo tep_input_search_jquery('keywords', '',INPUT_SEARCH, 'search'); ?>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#keywords').focus();
})
</script>

Comment: had a look at jsfiddle but still getting the need to refresh see see [my code](http://pastebin.com/H7C3gMeA)

Comment: Could you also provide the generated html? So, copy the source code of the page?

Comment: Throw away your own function 'focus'. In my code you forgot the '#' to specify an id.

Comment: yes tried that I get same result, i think the page is caching therefor not doing a load when i click the link (if i F5 it the focus then works).
As you can guess I am learning as i go along :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the autofocus attribute, no javascript needed for this ?

```
<input id="keywords" autofocus="autofocus" />
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you have, so there must be something else going on if it's not working.

Comment: this did create a input box but outside of the original input box?
<?php echo tep_input_search_jquery('keywords', '',INPUT_SEARCH, 'search'); ?>

Comment: You're using some sort of function in PHP to create the input, what plugin or framework are you using that has the tep_input function ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#keywords" ).focus(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .focus() called." );
});
```